# store value in database on click of a jquery function by fetching the values from a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.1

How to submit a select value on click of a jquery function and save the values in database and return to the same page?

I'm having this select box, This select box is not inside any form.

```
<select name="myRating" class="rating" id="serialStar">  
   <option value="1">Alright</option>  
   <option value="2">Ok</option>  
   <option value="3">Getting Better</option>  
   <option value="4">Awesome</option> 
   <option value="5">Loved!</option>  
</select>
```

I'm using below jQuery function to send the select value into a controller action 'set_ratings'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ui-rating").click(function(){
    // we want to store the values from the select box, then send via ajax below
    var fid = $('#serialStar').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/reelstubs/movies/set_ratings",
        data: "fid="+ fid
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Now I want to save the value into database. How can I achieve this?
Is the way proper?

Answer (score 1):

the url from ajax must not be relative path from localhost.

instead of

`url: "http://localhost/reelstubs/movies/set_ratings"`

use

`url: "../reelstubs/movies/set_ratings"` or where is your php file

The way to add value to database, learn from here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/  (this is an example)

good luck